# Simple c++ vector program not compiling

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm just starting to learn c++ and wrote this very simple program to use vectors. But it doesn't compile. I want to see the behavior of subscripting a non-existent element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<int> list;
    cout << list[0];
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile it on my mac using `cc main.cpp`, I get an incomprehensible error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-651b3f.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in main-651b3f.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-651b3f.o
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::~__vector_base() in main-651b3f.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in main-651b3f.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in main-651b3f.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in main-651b3f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`cLion` IDE doesn't complain about compilation issues for the same program. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: Probably `cc` is the C compiler driver - and it won't link with the C++ libraries. you want `c++` or something similar.

Comment: What are the `"using std::*"` lines for?

Comment: Try `c++` as your compiler, instead of `cc`.  It should link the runtime automatically for you.

Comment: @didiz "What are the "using std::*" lines for?" - seriously? You don't know what they do or you are confused why OP added them? I'll agree there are a few too many, but at least the ones for `vector` and `cout` make sense.

Comment: @didz Is that a serious question? So that he can use names like `vector`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Any idea why cLion IDE doesn't fail on this program. It just prints nothing. Running it on command line is giving ```segmentation fault```.

Comment: Normally I'd see `using namespace std;` for that, and around here that is not recommended, that is why I asked...

Comment: `list` is empty, you have undefined behavior. It might crash or do nothing.

Comment: @RandomQuestion [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43e8f9ec965a5d43)

Comment: I'm following c++ primer book right now. Not sure about the best practices.

Comment: @didiz bringing in just the bits you need rather than the whole `std` namespace is a good thing..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I simply don't enjoy people attacking someone because he dared to ask a question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What do you mean "no repro"? The output on your link clearly says "Segmentation fault".

Comment: @JesperJuhl: It was clearly an attack, and your own comments haven't been much better. Let's all move on.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition But doesn't reproduce the compiler errors mentioned in the question, Lightness Sir! So _no repro_ :-P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's because you're calling the right compiler. I thought, since you were responding to RandomQuestion, you were (like RandomQuestion) testing it _after_ fixing that problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Did you know? Repeatedly ordering people to "relax" often has the opposite effect.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Sure. I usually know what I'm doing ;-)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition whatever...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cc` is a command to build C programs. Write `c++` instead.

These are typically aliases to executables like `gcc` and `g++` (respectively), or `clang` and `clang++` (respectively).

Even if these executables ultimately invoke the same front-end (which is usually true), it matters which command you invoke. For example, the `cc` alias will not result in the C++ standard library being linked in, which is precisely the problem you're seeing.

By the way, your program has undefined behaviour since you're trying to output an element that doesn't exist. So, *technically*, you could even get this result after fixing the build command ;)

Comment: no idea what downvoter thought.. another posibily could be that file was named *.c

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to compile a C++ code with C compiler. You should use a proper C++ compiler (e.g. `c++`) instead.

The other thing is that there's an undefined behaviour in your program:

```
vector<int> list;
cout << list[0];
```

Vectors are always initialized as empty. So you try to access an element that doesn't exist yet. This will most likely result in a segfault. Try inserting something:

```
vector<int> list;
list.push_back(1);
cout << list[0];
```

Comment: The problem is not the compiler, it's the linker.

Comment: The nit-picking is real.